# 'cblas.h' error while installing Caffe on Mac OS

Tags: macos, caffe

I followed the instructions to install Caffe (CPU only) on mac, there's an error when I run "make -j".

```
In file included from src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp:5:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.hpp:9:
In file included from ./include/caffe/layer.hpp:12:
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/math_functions.hpp:11:
./include/caffe/util/mkl_alternate.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'cblas.h' file not found
#include <cblas.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o] Error 1
```

I modified the makefile.config by adding lines:

```
USE_BLAS = apple
ADD_LDFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib
ADD_CFLAGS =  -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to: `brew uninstall openblas; brew install --fresh -vd openblas`.

next, add two build flags:

```
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib

CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include
```

Comment: This worked for me. You 'add two build flags' by editing the lines for `BLAS_INCLUDE` and `BLAS_LIB` in the `Makefile.config` as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Z.Kal's answer didn't help in my case, but I noticed that in case you installed the dependencies through homebrew (like I did), these two lines need uncommenting:

```
# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib
```

Worked like a charm for me afterwards! Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: This works for me! Also, please choose "open" rather than "atlas".

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include ..
```

It works very well for me.